# Error while passing arguments to events function

Tags: matlab, ode

I have a function called `initial` which takes an argument `funname` and performs some integration. I wanted to pass multiple arguments to events function. So I did this:

```
odeopt=odeset('RelTol',1e-5,'AbsTol',1e-5,'Events',@(t,y) events(t,y,prm,funname));
fun=str2func(funname);
[t,y]=ode15s(fun,[0 3600],z,odeopt,prm);
```

`prm` is a structure and `funname` is a string.

This is the events function:

```
function [value,isterminal,direction] = events(t,y,prm,funname)

isterminal=1;
direction=0;
v=feval(funname,1,y,prm);
value=~all(v<1e-10);
```

funname is basically the ode function.

It still says too many input arguments.:

```
??? Error using ==> initial>@(t,y)events(t,y,prm,funname)
Too many input arguments.

Error in ==> odeevents at 29
  eventValue = feval(eventFcn,t0,y0,eventArgs{:});

Error in ==> ode15s at 263
[haveEventFcn,eventFcn,eventArgs,valt,teout,yeout,ieout] = ...

Error in ==> initial at 10
[t,y]=ode15s(fun,[0 3600],z,odeopt,prm);
```

Can't be a problem of version (was using 7.6) because this [post](http://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/123482) which addresses this issue was on 2006.

Any Idea?

Comment: I think since you're are passing `prm` as an extra parameter in the `ode15s` call, the `eventArgs` cells array has the value and `odeevents` is essentially performing `events(t,y,prm)`.

Comment: i removed `prm` from the event function (and in `odeset` as well) but it still is giving the same error.

Comment: Removing it from the event function doesn't matter if the `events` handle is defined as `(t,y)`; trying changing the handle to `(t,y,prm)`.

Comment: That somewhat worked. New error : `Undefined function or method 'sign' for input arguments of type 'logical'`.

Comment: That might stem from your event function's value being a logical.  Multiply it by 1 or add a 0 to convert `value` to double or use `double()`.

Comment: Ahh.. thats what it was.. can you please post it as an answer (your first comment)

Comment: Done.  I just wanted to make sure that was the cause before posting the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `prm` is passed as the last argument in `ode15s`, it will result in the `eventArgs` cell passing the value to the event handle. In other words, the line

```
eventValue = feval(eventFcn,t0,y0,eventArgs{:});
```

is really doing

```
eventValue = eventFcn(t,y,prm);
```

So if `prm` is needed as an extra parameter in the ODE system, just make `prm` an input in the event handle:

```
odeopt=odeset(..., @(t,y,prm) events(t,y,prm,funname));
```

---

Also, since the events function is design to locate solutions passing through zeros, the `value` should be a double such that MATLAB's `sign` function works properly.